# How to get line of intersection of two moving planes as line object with boolean intersection?

Tags: modifiers

I want to get line of intersection of two planes as line object when the planes move.

I tried live boolean intersection, however, it just vanish.

Further I want to use intersection line for some operation, without fixing it by applying boolean.

[image: Video description]

[image]

Comment: Are you using 2.91 version? Boolean is improved now.

Comment: Yes it's blender 2.91

Comment: Has the green plane some thickness?